# Content hiding above div's

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an adept knowledge in HTML/CSS but I'm having a problem that has more than stooped me. In order to test my skills, I build websites on TV Shows etc, and while designing one, I've ran into a problem. As seen in the screenshot, although I've declared the div after the previous one, it seems to be hiding.

As you can see. I've tried both paragraph tags and divs, nothing seems to be working, I've included the HTML and CSS.

```css
body {
 padding:0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Raleway';

}

.nav {
 background-color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: silver;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav > li {
 display: block;
}

/* .nav > li:before {
 content: "*";
} */

.nav > li > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: silver;
 font-size:24px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bolder;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.nav-btn {
 display:block;
 font-size: 30px;
 background-color: black;
 color: silver;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.image {
 background-image:url('download1.jpg');
 width:100%;
    max-height:400px;
    background-position: left center absolute;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
}

.title {
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 position:relative;
 margin: 15%;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.image {
 text-align: center;
 position:absolute;
}

.image > h2 {
 padding-top: 50%;
 line-height: 50%;

}


@media screen and (max-width: 411px) {
 .title > h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
 }

 .image {
  max-height:280px;
 }
}

.submitbox {
 color: yellow;
 background-color: darkblue;
 z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to France!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Reign.css" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <div id="header">"Today I am King!"</div> -->
<nav>
 <span class="nav-btn">Menu</span>
  <ul class="nav">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
<div class="image"><div class="title"><h2>"Today, I am king!"<br />Mary, Queen of Scots.</h2></div></div>
<div id="submitbox"><h2>Sign up for our Newsletter!</h2></div>
<p>hello</p>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('span.nav-btn').click(function () {
 $('ul.nav').toggle();
});
</script>
</body>
```

Some of that code isn't relevant to what I'm asking. Also, I have a menu but it's open when the page loads, and idea how I can get this to be closed on page load? Also running the code snippet doesn't illustrate what I'm saying as the image is missing.

EDIT: important was used to try and bring the H2 to the front of the image, which cannot be seen when running the code snippet. I used position abolute so when anything is adjusted it will not affect said styles, sorry If I'm doing that wrong. Also changed the images.

EDIT2: I just realised why I used position absolute, it was to stop the image getting white bars above and below the image when the window is scaled down
[White bars?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0RPv.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain the need for `position: absolute` and why you have `!important` BTW `submitbox` is an ID, should be `#submitbox` in CSS

Comment: I believe your two image links are identical images. the i.stack.imgur ones.

Comment: I made this edit below in my post, but also just letting you know here that you use `div id="submitbox"` but reference it in css with the wrong selector `.submitbox` when it should be `#submitbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your menu issue, just set `display:none;` to your `.nav` and it will start not visible. For your other issue, I believe having your position set to absolute is what is causing the issue. By changing it to `position:relative` (and making the background green so you can see it), the div shows up and doesn't block the newsletter text. Absolute div's don't care what else is around it. It will be position relative to its nearest ancestor if set to absolute, which in the case of your HTML, is the `<body>`

Also, you label `id="submitbox"` but reference it in css with `.submitbox` instead of `#submitbox`

```css
body {
 padding:0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Raleway';

}

.nav {
    display:none;
 background-color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: silver;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav > li {
 display: block;
}

/* .nav > li:before {
 content: "*";
} */

.nav > li > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: silver;
 font-size:24px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bolder;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.nav-btn {
 display:block;
 font-size: 30px;
 background-color: black;
 color: silver;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.image {
 background-image:url('download1.jpg');
 width:100%;
    max-height:400px;
    background-position: left center absolute;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
}

.title {
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 position:relative;
 margin: 15%;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.image {
 text-align: center;
 position:relative;
  background-color:green;
}

.image > h2 {
 padding-top: 50%;
 line-height: 50%;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 411px) {
 .title > h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
 }

 .image {
  max-height:280px;
 }
}

.submitbox {
 color: yellow;
 background-color: darkblue;
 z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to France!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Reign.css" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <div id="header">"Today I am King!"</div> -->
<nav>
 <span class="nav-btn">Menu</span>
  <ul class="nav">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
<div class="image"><div class="title"><h2>"Today, I am king!"<br />Mary, Queen of Scots.</h2></div></div>
<div id="submitbox"><h2>Sign up for our Newsletter!</h2></div>
<p>hello</p>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('span.nav-btn').click(function () {
 $('ul.nav').toggle();
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Edit2 above, I see why I positioned absolute.

Comment: Sure thing. I'm not sure if the way I positioned this is how you want it, but the menu display:none thing I am certain of :)

Comment: Thanks for that too, I ran that and it worked, not that I doubted you. Just one more thing, any way to get rid of these white bars now when the window is resized? http://i.stack.imgur.com/l0RPv.jpg I'm thinking that my div is too long or something and the image isn't big enough or something, or I'm totally wrong?

Comment: I can't see the console so could you tell me what elements it says the white space is a part of? The snippet I wrote above doesn't have the white.

Comment: Sorry about that. When viewing in full width, the top white bar disappears and the image aligns with the header neatly and apparently, the bottom white bar is part of the h2. When minimizing, it seems that the image forms a white bar at the bottom and top as seen here http://prntscr.com/alqn5z

Comment: @Luke Assuming the css information for .image in my snippet is the same as yours, I would try cleaning up the background css information you have there a bit. Delete some of it, alter it a bit, etc. and see what that does. You alter background-position, the overall position, background size %, overall max-height 400px (try getting rid of that too). Unfortunately, I can't really offer much more advice than that here. I'm trying to get better with CSS myself.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look. Thank you for all of your help :)