# Image doesn't fill div when window resized

Tags: html, css

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294319/content-hiding-above-divs/36294528), I've managed to figure it out, but when resizing the window, the h2 still presents a margin, which I've just removed by removing 20px from the h2, which I shouldn't have to do, however, this still presents a problem. When I resize the window, the divs do not follow the image and I'm left seeing the background. Is there any way I can fix this without having to  remove 20px from every h2? But still have no gap/nothing breaks when resizing the window. If you view the snippet full window then resize your browser window you'll see what I mean.

```css
body {
 padding:0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Raleway';

}

.nav {
    display:none;
 background-color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: silver;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav > li {
 display: block;
}

/* .nav > li:before {
 content: "*";
} */

.nav > li > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: silver;
 font-size:24px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bolder;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.nav-btn {
 display:block;
 font-size: 30px;
 background-color: black;
 color: silver;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.image {
 background-image:url('https://www.wbnx.com/uploads/downloads/cover_art/850x315_reign_mary.jpg');
 width:100%;
    max-height:400px;
    background-position: left center absolute;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
}

.title {
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 position:relative;
 margin: 15%;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.image {
 text-align: center;
 position:relative;
  background-color:green;
}

.image > h2 {
 padding-top: 50%;
 line-height: 50%;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 411px) {
 .title > h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
 }

 .image {
  max-height:280px;
 }
}

.submitbox {
 color: yellow;
 background-color: darkblue;
 padding:0;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to France!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Reign.css" type="text/css1">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <div id="header">"Today I am King!"</div> -->
<nav>
 <span class="nav-btn">Menu</span>
  <ul class="nav">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
<div class="image"><div class="title"><h2>"Today, I am king!"<br />Mary, Queen of Scots.</h2></div></div>
<div class="submitbox"><h2>Sign up for our Newsletter!</h2></div>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('span.nav-btn').click(function () {
 $('ul.nav').toggle();
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: There is still a margin on the `h2` element, because its default margin haven't been reset. Applying a negative margin to `.submitbox`, thought effecting the position of `h2` on the page, does not effect the margin of `h2`. If you want to remove the margin from h2, simply write `h2 { margin: 0; }`, no need of a negative margin. To fill in the container area with the image, write `background-size: cover;` instead of `background-size: 100%;`.

Comment: That worked. Thank's so much!